# Angular UI-Bootstrap carousel not working in a latest version 2.5.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am tring to achieve angular carousel. But it is not working in the latest version. But it is working fine in a older version.

Please look at the following plunkr.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mjXtFt9drbmwPFQG3f9i?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);
app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl);

function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
  $scope.myInterval = 3000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  $scope.active = 0;
  $scope.slides = [
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
        Write your name here       <input type="text" ng-model="name" />

        Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:  
              <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
        <div>
          <uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
            <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="active" index="$index">
              <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
              </div>
            </uib-slide>
          </uib-carousel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here , the **ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js** version is 1.2.1, If I use the latest version istead of this ( 2.5.0 )

**"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"**  carousel is not working.

Can anyone help me what change am i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is that the new version of Angular Bootstrap UI uses directives instead of components.

Have a look at this updated [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UHbfM7txK8FXywYBkTM3?p=preview)

I have changed the html code to be like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    Write your name here
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
      <div>
        <div uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
          <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="active" index="$index">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But the problem is it is not sliding for me. I am using ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js 2.5.0 version ,bootstrap.min.css, angular-animate and all. But for me only the second  card is active. If I click also it not going forward or backward.

Comment: Yes I had that before and it looks like the images are not loaded correctly every time. If you keep refreshing the page you will eventually the set. What browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using chrome